# objective-c hide round rect buttons

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have three buttons centered on my view called btn_easy, btn_medium, btn_hard. I want to hide all three of these buttons when I click one of them: My .h file has the outlets and method defined as follows:

```
    IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_easy;
    IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_medium;
    IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_hard;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_easy;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_medium;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_hard;

    -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

After defining these IBOutlets in my .h file I open Interface Builder and make the Connection Outlets from each button from "touch up inside" reference outlet to the "File's Owner".  My .m file has the following synthesis:

```
  @synthesize btn_easy,btn_medium,btn_hard;
```

And I've tried the following methods in my .m file as well:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
  if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"easy"]){
      NSLog(@"easy clicked");
  }
  if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"medium"]){
      NSLog(@"medium clicked");
  }
  if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"hard"]){
      NSLog(@"hard clicked");
  }
  cover_page.hidden = YES;
  btn_easy.hidden = YES;
  btn_medium.hidden = YES;
  btn_hard.hidden = YES;
  loadingCover.hidden = YES;
 }
```

but neither of these seem to work for hiding the buttons.  I know the method executes correctly however because I have other functions within the method that execute properly, it is just the button hiding that does not work.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Xcode, so I've retagged this.

Comment: Are you sure you've connected the outlets properly via IB for each of the buttons, and that the buttonPressed action really is getting called?

Comment: I've added more explanation to my OP

Comment: Set a breakpoint in buttonPressed and confirm that btn_easy, btn_medium, and btn_hard are not NULL.  If they are NULL, your outlets are not connected properly.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make sure that each of your buttons are declared as IBOutlets,

Then make sure inside Interface Builder that your IBAction is connected to each button and your IBOutlets are connected to each corresponding button.

Instead of using hidden try the alpha/opacity being set to 0.

Should be a very simple fix and if this doesn't work then I imagine there is some other code interfacing with those buttons that is stopping from this event happening.

Comment: Why do you recommend changing the `alpha` property instead of the `hidden` property?

Comment: Well, I don't believe there is any difference between them, however it was just an idea as this problem doesn't seem to have many possible solutions due to its simplicity I was trying to look as every possibility, no matter how unlikely. In other words, just one of those things you try in order to get functionality. You never know.

Comment: I've updated my OP to show other things I've tried and elaborate more on how I created my Connection Outlets.  Please advise...

Comment: Hmm, its a really odd that it doesn't work. Do you have any other code that interfaces with these buttons? Definitely have each button outlet go to each button in interface builder? So from the files owner you need to connect the btn_easy outlet to the easy button in your interface and same with the others. Then connect the buttonPressed IBAction to each button using touch up inside as you said. I mean if they are connected correctly I don't see whats wrong. Of course if your IBOutlets aren't connected your IBAction won't do anything. Must be an unseen factor that you have't shown us.

Comment: check my OP again as I've added what the ENTIRE buttonPressed method looks like (I omitted some stuff before because I didn't think it was relevant, but I'll let you determine if it is interfering or not).

Answer (score 0):

Use this!

```
 if([[YourButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:@"Text"])
{

}
else {
```

}